# jquery: differences in how literal string selector vs variable selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping, delimiter, backslash

I have some code that has a '.' character in a css class name, therefore an escape is required to find the element using a selector `$('.classNameWithDot\\.inIt')`

I ran into an interesting bug whereby if you store the selector in a variable it will not work as expected unless you change how you escape the dot character from two to one backslash.

```
//will not work
//var selector = '.classNameWithDot\\.inIt';

//works in a variable, with one backslash as opposed to the required double backslash for the literal
var selector = '.classNameWithDot\.inIt';

var element = $(selector);
```

My question is why is this the case? Why must we use double backslash in the literal selector and single for the variable selector?

Comment: `'.classNameWithDot\.inIt'` results in `.classNameWithDot.inIt`, so I doubt your observations are correct. Whether you use a string literal or variable doesn't matter. Unless you can reproduce that behavior with a http://jsfiddle.net/ (or something similar) I assume your actual problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This fiddle does not match your description: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/zf4daLxt/

Comment: The class name does not begin with a 'dot'. Ex: 'someName.restOfName'. @FelixKling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a JavaScript **string literal**(this is when the string is typed out in the source code) `\` has a special meaning and if you want to have it in a string you'll have to escape it with a `\`( which is the escaping character).

```
var str = 'a slash(\\)';
```

> a slash(\)

Now in jQuery selectors a dot is a special character and you guessed it need to be escaped

> #id.class

As a selector this means select element with id `id` and class `class`, but what if your id was `id.class` then the dot needs to be escaped.

> #id.class

Now this is the selector you're looking for, an element with an id of `id.class`
Now how do we write this in js

```
var str = '#id\.class';
```

> #id.class

That didn't work because `\` is the escape character in js and we don't want the `.` escaped in js we want it escaped in the jQuery selector engine.
So we must escape the escape character (with itself).

```
var str = '#id\\.class';/*
      this____||  
      escapes  |
      this_____|        */
```

> #id\.class

now you can pass your selector to jQuery

Comment: Thanks Musa, your explanation clarified the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have your test cases backwards.

I made a jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/xuxixarimuhe/1/

The double backslash allows you to actually enter a backslash in a string, otherwise it means to create an escape sequence.

So the double backslash is required so that you can actually put a \ in your selector.

That being said...I highly recommend, if you can, removing periods in a css classname, I didn't even know you could do that.

Thanks for the nerd snipe ;)

- Craig